# Number of divisors of a number - in NP?

Tags: turing-machines, np-complete

I'm trying to show that the language $\{(m,n) | m \space \text{has exactly} \space n \space \text{divisors}\}$ is in NP.

The input $(m,n)$ is in **binary**.

The non-deterministic Turing machine for the language would be:

1) Guess the prime factors of $m.$

2) Verify that $\prod i(di+1) = n.$

The problem is that I can't find a way to **factorize in polynomial time** (in the input) the number $m.$

If stage $1$ takes m steps then it would be $m = 2^{\log (m)}$ and the whole algorithm would run in exponential time.

How can I factorize a number in binary in polynomial time (polynomial in the input)?

Comment: As far as I know, it is an open problem whether integer factorization is in $P$ or not. No efficient (that is polynomial in time) method is currently known.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty_and_complexity

Comment: The whole point is that on a non-deterministic turing machine you can guess the correct solution non-deterministically in a single step... you only need to verify it in polynomial time.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen   But the problem is that the amount of numbers i need to guess for the correct answer might be polynomial in the size of the binary input. If i have log(m) bits and we have m factors that would be m = 2 ^ (logm) --> exponential

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  Edit: i meant if we have log(m) bits and the number of factors is O(m) = O(2 ^ log(m))

Comment: The number of prime factors of $m$ is logarithmic in $m.$ And in any event this has nothing to do with 'factorizing a number in polynomial time', just 'listing the (known) factors in polynomial time'. (Though if the latter were impossible, the former would be trivially impossible, rather than probably impossible, but a hard open question.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen How can i prove that the number of prime factors of a given integer m is O(logm) ?

Comment: What's the smallest number with $5$ prime factors?

Comment: I need a formal proof. Also, in the Turing machine i need to know the exact number of steps to make in order to guess the prime factors, not just O(log(m))

Comment: The fact that the smallest number with $n$ prime factors is $2^n$ proves that the number of prime factors of $m$ is bounded above by $\log_2(m).$ I'm not sure what you mean by or why you need the exact number of steps... anyway, the details will depend on your precise definitions and implementation. The idea is that for a NDTM, the naive algorithm k=2; while m != 1: (if k|m: factors.append(k); m /= k else: k+=1) only has to visit the correct $k$'s, so there are as many iterations of the loop as prime factors. (And everything inside is polynomial.)